# Nbspinner Background color changed

Tags: angular, spinner, nebular

I want to changed the background color of the nbspinner.
I already tried nb theme variable but its not worked for me.

```
@import "~@nebular/theme/styles/theming";
@import "~@nebular/theme/styles/themes/default";

$nb-themes: nb-register-theme(
  (
    background-color: red,
  ),
  default
);
```

Answer (score 0):

While registering theme you have to use the variable name: **spinner-basic-background-color** it will definitely work as it worked for me. You can also check the other colors related to nb-spinner in below docs.

[Nebular Docs](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/spinner/theme#nbspinnercomponent)

```
$nb-themes: nb-register-theme((
  font-family-primary: unquote('Roboto, sans-serif'),
  font-family-secondary: font-family-primary,
  spinner-basic-background-color: red,
), default-ltr, default );
```